# Simple spinner get position specific value

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have a simple `Spinner` implemented as:

```
vehicle = json.getJSONArray("vehicle");
for(int i = 0; i < vehicle.length(); i++){
    JSONObject c = vehicle.getJSONObject(i);
    //put json obkject on variable
    String id = c.getString("id");
    String name = c.getString("name");
    String capacity = c.getString("capacity");
    String cost = c.getString("cost");
    String v = name + " ("+capacity + " Liters)";
    vehicleList.add(v);
    // Set Spinner Adapter
    mySpinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(OrderDetails.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,vehicleList));
    // Spinner on item click listener
    mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0,View arg1, int position, long arg3) {  
            car = vehicleList.get(+position); 
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), car, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            car = null;
        }
    });                     
}
```

I wanted to grab the value of "ID" in the car variable. Is it possible with above implementation?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to replace your item click listener with this ...

```
mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
            int position, long id) {
        int spinnerItem = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
        car = vehicleList.get(spinnerItem);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), selectedId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();     
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // nothing to do here :|
    }
});
```

**//EDIT**
you can create another list that hold values of IDs ... and then add values to it as vehicleList ...

```
idList.add(id);
```

and then just call when item is selected in spinner

```
String selectedId = idList.get(spinnerItem);
```

Comment: This is somehow the same as my implementation. I need to see `name + " ("+capacity + " Liters)";` on the spinner item but when selected I want just `id` which is on `String id = c.getString("id");`

Comment: Your implementation will toast `name + " ("+capacity + " Liters)"` . I want to toast just ID which is on id variable.

Answer (score 0):

Returns the position selected.

```
  mySpinner.getSelectedItem()
```

or

```
mySpinner.getSelectedItemPosition()
```